# Using Gloox with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gloox

I am trying to use the [gloox](http://camaya.net/gloox/) library (C++) to create a Windows XMPP application. It seems simple enough, except I don't know how to import gloox into Visual Studio 2010 so I can include it in my application project.

I've looked at the instructions provided in the read-me (shown below), but when I try to compile the library, I get this error:

> Cannot open source file: 'src\tlsgnutlsserver.cpp': No such file or directory

Instructions provided in the read-me file:

> ### Building gloox on MSVC++
>
> - use the included project file or create your own
> - adjust include + library paths if necessary
> - to receive any debug output you should use the LogSink facilities (this is not win32-specific)
> - build

Does anyone have experience using Gloox with VS10? If yes, can you please help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using the official 1.0 tarball? I had the same problem (missing source file) and had to acquire the source from SVN instead. I used the 1.0 branch.

I encountered a few other build problems, namely

- the release build configuration was set to build an **Application (.exe)** instead of **Dynamic library (.dll)** (Project->Properties->General->Configuration Type)
- I needed to add **DLL_EXPORT** to the preprocessor definitions (Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++ ->Properties->Preprocessor)
- **src\atomicrefcount.cpp** needed to be added to the project's source files. (Project->Add Existing Item)

This worked for me in express editions of both VC++ 2010 and VC++ 2008.

Hopefully it helps you as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben. This helped me significantly, so I've made some small changes to make it even simpler for others.

Comment: @TusharDhoot No problem, I should have mentioned that I later reported the problem upstream with a patch: http://bugs.camaya.net/horde3/whups/ticket/?id=197  I'm not sure how active gloox development is lately but it couldn't hurt :)